# Does morphia support GridFS?

Tags: gridfs, morphia

Is there a implementation of GridFS in Morphia? How is this?

I am using a webservice and receive base64 input, which is transform in a bit array, such like this:

```
private bit [] image;
```

I created my model class to communicate with morphia, however, each document of that collection will have a lot of images, is something like an event has a lot of editions and an edition has its images.

How can I mapped that attribute in morphia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridFS is not yet supported by Morphia, if you want to store information into GridFS from your application you need to use the native Java GridFS API ( see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/test/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSTest.java )

To answer your question

> How can I mapped that attribute in morphia?

The code you have written will work, and your images will be saved as bytes into the document, in the attribute "image" like any other attribute. As you probably know MongoDB & Morphia are using BSON in memor, on the network and in the database, this means it will save the bytes as they are sent.

So of you still want to store the image in the document, not an issue at all if they are small, you just have to be careful about the overall size of the document. As you probably know a document cannot exceed 16Mb.